# n_dead_tup vs dead_tuple_count in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I initially thought `n_dead_tup` and `dead_tuple_count` in PostgreSQL give the same counts. But they seem to be not. I do not quite understand what exactly is difference.

Following are my observations:

1. Created a table with 10k rows.
2. Updated all the 10k rows. Now I have 10k dead tuples.

```
SELECT dead_tuple_count FROM public.pgstattuple('public.vacuum_test');

 dead_tuple_count 
------------------
            10002

select * from pg_stat_get_dead_tuples('18466');

 pg_stat_get_dead_tuples 
-------------------------
                   10002
```

3. I did vacuum full on the table. As expected dead_tuple_count is 0.

```
SELECT dead_tuple_count FROM public.pgstattuple('public.vacuum_test');

 dead_tuple_count 
------------------
                0
```

But `n_dead_tup` from `pg_stat_all_tables` i.e `pg_stat_get_dead_tuples('18466')` is still 10002:

```
select * from pg_stat_get_dead_tuples('18466');

 pg_stat_get_dead_tuples 
-------------------------
                   10002
```

I repeated this process several times and observed that number of updated tuples is getting added to the stat `n_dead_tup` after every update.

So what exactly is `VACUUM` doing here?
And what is the difference between `n_dead_tup` and `dead_tuple_count`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pgstattuple` scans the tables and calculates real-time results. It can be quite slow for a big table, but produces accurate results.

Access to the `pg_stat` views, directly or via functions like `pg_stat_get_dead_tuples`, uses the *most recent data collected by `ANALYZE`*. So it can be out of date, especially if you just made big changes. However, it's very fast to access.

If you `ANALYZE` the table, the stats will match again, or close. They'll often not be exactly the same because the stats from `ANALYZE` are just estimates.

BTW, it's time to upgrade from 8.4 to something current.

Answer (score 0):

`VACUUM FULL` is a little buggy in that it doesn't reset those statistics counters.  An ordinary `VACUUM` would do so.